# Python Django - django-filters app - autogenerate searchfield based on model

Tags: python, django, search, django-forms, django-filter

Alright,

First time I'm asking a question over here, i did search for similar question but haven't found my answer yet..

I'm working on a simple delivery app with Django, it shows an overview of customers checkin in and out and some details on the delivery.

I have a view called "CheckInsListView" and "CheckOutListView" and i would like to filter these lists on a user given date, based on the django-filters app.

I tried following this link: https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/11/28/how-to-filter-querysets-dynamically.html

The problem now is, the searchform is not automatically created. It does show the submit button but the formfield isn't generated. It doesn't come up with any errors either.

Can somebody point out what I'm missing here?

Thanks in advance,

Kevin

```
#filters.py
   from .models import Delivery
   import django_filters

   class DeliveryFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):

    class Meta:
        model = Delivery
        fields = ['arrival_date']
```

Adding the view:

```
#views.py  
"""
Create a search view to sort deliveries on date, django-filter app is used
"""

from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Delivery
from .filters import DeliveryFilter

def search(request):
    delivery_list = Delivery.objects.all()
    delivery_filter = DeliveryFilter(request.GET, queryset=delivery_list)
    return render(request, 'all_deliveries.html', {'filter': delivery_filter})
```

And urls

```
#urls.py
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'^search/$', views.search, name='search'),
]
```

The form in html

```
{% extends "framework.html" %}

{% block content %}

<div class="form_search_header">
        <form method="get">
            {{ filter.form.as_p }}
            <button type="submit">Search</button>
        </form>
</div>

{% endblock %}
```

Comment: I think you forgot to add `{% csrf_token %}` in the form

Comment: I do not think i need the csrf token, csrf token is used with method="post"...

Answer (score 0):

```
delivery_filter = DeliveryFilter(request.GET, queryset=delivery_list)
```

This is still going to return filtered records. There you need to write a `for` loop in the template, something like below:

```
<option value="" disabled selected>Select Delivery Item</option>
{% for d in filter %}
<option value="{{ d.id }}">{{ d.arrival_date }}</option>
{% endfor %}
```